# Does a Java library act like a Windows DLL?

Tags: windows, java, libraries

This is a pretty simple question I've been having for a while. A Java library contains classes that a Java program can use to improve how the program works, such as LWJGL. I was wondering if a DLL is similar, containing pieces of code that a program can use to improve how it works, like a window renderer.

Comment: No; There are nothing alike.

Comment: In intent, maybe. In form, fit, or function, no.

Comment: _"A [...] library contains classes that a [...] program can use to improve how the program works"_ - no, this is incorrect. In almost all cases programs rely on specific libraries to work at all.